# How make sense of this battery graph on a Watch 6?

Tags: battery, charging, apple-watch

I've a watch series 6 here that is behaving quite bizarrely. Mostly when the charger is attached it does some reboot loop with the apple logo appearing every 5 minutes or so. I think this is because it's charging a bit, then powering on, then running out of power, then charging a bit.

Last night I checked on it and it said 35% - oh good, I thought, it's finally broken its cycle. This morning it's back to looping.

I managed to get a photo of the battery screen but I don't really understand it and it seems to contradict itself:

[image]

Last charged to 35% seems right; it's what I remember, but the graph seems to say it charged to 100% which contradicts the words. It also looks like it charged to 100% by 1am but at 3am all the power abruptly disappeared from the battery?

Also, there's a pause symbol on the x axis and a charge symbol - so the watch was attached to a charger all day but charging was paused, then it suddenly started charging?

Can anyone help me interpret this screen and give me an indication of what the graph should look like? Does this graph look sensible?

Is it likely the battery in the watch has an issue and needs to be replaced, or is it the charger, or the software?